# How to convert a percentage into a numeric value, using the percent and total, replacing the percentage value with the whole numeric value

Tags: r, percentage, numeric, data-conversion, mutate

```
df <- read.csv(ACSST1Y2010.S2001-2022-11-11T181908.csv) 

view(df)
```

[image]

This is the table I'm using for Income Data from the Census.
I'm attempting to find the numeric values of the 2nd column, that are currently percentages. I would like to know how to convert these percentages into numeric values, the amount of people in each grouping. I have the total amount of people surveyed, so how can I take that information and parse out the values from the percentages and total.

I figured mutate would be involved and maybe parse...I just don't know how to code it.

This was my attempt...

```
  mutate((Individual_Income_Census_2010[4:12,2]*96447572)/100)
```

This is the error message:

Error in `mutate()`:
! Problem while computing `..1 = (Individual_Income_Census_2010[4:12, 2] * 96447572)/100`.
Caused by error in `FUN()`:
! non-numeric argument to binary operator
Run `rlang::last_error()` to see where the error occurred.

> rlang::last_error()
> <error/dplyr:::mutate_error>

Not sure what to try next. Still working on my beginning coding abilities.

I would like to replace the values in the column, from row 4 to 12, or [4:12, 2] in R talk, with the newfound calculated whole number, representing the percentage of the total previously taking up space in the column. Also, I don't know how to replicate the table, seeing as how the read.csv here doesn't actually do anything, therefore the screen shot of the data.

Comment: Please do not post (only) an image of code/data/errors: it breaks screen-readers and it cannot be copied or searched (ref: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557 and https://xkcd.com/2116/). Please include the code, console output, or data (e.g., `data.frame(...)` or the output from `dput(head(x))`) directly.

Comment: But clearly your data is not numeric, it's `character`, based on the presence of thousands-separators (`,`), the `%` in some, and the sole `(X)` we can see at the bottom. From this, no math function is going to work, you need to first extract the numbers into a `numeric` field.

Comment: I rm() the dataframe and re-loaded it so I could change the class from character to numeric in the 2nd column. I tried to change through coding but that gave me NA values for the whole column...incorrect. So now I have numeric values and I created a function to find the whole numbers I was looking for.

Comment: doing_it <- function(x=Individual_Income_Census_2010[4:12]){
  y <- x*96447572/100
  return(y)
}

Comment: these_them_answers <- doing_it(Individual_Income_Census_2010[4:12,2])

Comment: Now I have the values I wanted in the first place, but how do I get them into the particular cells I want? I want the cells [4:12, 2] to be replaced with the new values I have created using my function. Mutate() won't allow me to replace just a few cells, it is requiring all cells be changed or just the first cell. Here is the error message:       Individual_Income_Census_2010 %>% 
  transmute(Individual_Income_Census_2010[4:12,2], these_them_answers)

Comment: That was my code, here is the error that code gets: Error in `transmute()`:
! Problem while computing `..1 = Individual_Income_Census_2010[4:12, 2]`.
✖ `..1` must be size 23 or 1, not 9.
Run `rlang::last_error()` to see where the error occurred.

Comment: You should (almost) "never" use `[`-indexing within dplyr verbs like that. Does my answer not work for your real data?

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```r
quux <- tibble(estimate = c("158,884,879", "-28,899", "2.2%", "15.5%", "(X)"))
fun <- function(vec) {
  vec2 <- suppressWarnings(as.numeric(gsub("[^-.0-9]", "", vec)))
  vec2 / ifelse(grepl("%", vec), 100, 1)
}
quux %>%
  mutate(numbers = fun(estimate))
# # A tibble: 5 x 2
#   estimate          numbers
#   <chr>               <dbl>
# 1 158,884,879 158884879    
# 2 -28,899        -28899    
# 3 2.2%                0.022
# 4 15.5%               0.155
# 5 (X)                NA
```

As far as number-detection and extraction, this is certainly not water-tight, but it works well with the sample data (plus I added in a negative for good measure).